# index 18 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a little problem regarding my code where I'm trying to make pairs of test images for later comparison in few shot learning. My code is the following:

```
def make_oneshot_task(N, s="val", language=None):
    """Create pairs of test image, support set for testing N way one-shot learning. """
    if s == 'train':
        X = Xtrain
        X= X.reshape(-1,11,100,100,3)
        categories = train_classes
    else:
        X = X_val
        X= X.reshape(-1,4,100,100,3)
        categories = val_classes
    n_examples, n_classes, w, h, chan = X.shape
    #n_samples, n_examples, w, h = X.shape
    
    n_examples = 40
    n_classes = 11
    
    indices = rng.randint(0, n_examples,size=(N,))
    if language is not None: # if language is specified, select characters for that language
        low, high = categories[language]
        if N > high - low:
            raise ValueError("This language ({}) has less than {} letters".format(language, N))
        categories = rng.choice(range(low,high),size=(N,),replace=True)

    else: # if no language specified just pick a bunch of random letters
        categories = rng.choice(range(n_classes),size=(N,),replace=True)            
    
    true_category = categories[0]
    ex1, ex2 = rng.choice(n_examples,replace=True,size=(2,))
    test_image = np.asarray([X[true_category,ex1,:,:,:]]*N).reshape(N, w, h,3)
    support_set = X[categories,indices,:,:,:]
    support_set[0,:,:] = X[true_category,ex2]
    support_set = support_set.reshape(N, w, h,3)
    targets = np.zeros((N,))
    targets[0] = 1
    targets, test_image, support_set = shuffle(targets, test_image, support_set)
    pairs = [test_image,support_set]

    return pairs, targets
```

My main concern is that I'm getting an error at `test_image = np.asarray([X[true_category,ex1,:,:,:]]*N).reshape(N, w, h,3)`. Here is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-c6b9166704d8> in <module>
----> 1 make_oneshot_task(11)

<ipython-input-37-67c1a13297ca> in make_oneshot_task(N, s, language)
     27     true_category = categories[0]
     28     ex1, ex2 = rng.choice(n_examples,replace=True,size=(2,))
---> 29     test_image = np.asarray([X[true_category,ex1,:,:]]*N).reshape(N, w, h,3)
     30     support_set = X[categories,indices,:,:,:]
     31     support_set[0,:,:] = X[true_category,ex2]

IndexError: index 18 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4
```

Can anybody help me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X has shape:

```
X= X.reshape(-1,4,100,100,3)
```

You are calling:

```
X[true_category,ex1,:,:]
```

Where ex1 is 18 which exceed 4.